# Dataset has changes for new row

Tags: vb.net

I just notice that if the user modifies something in a `DataGridView` and also selects the last (new) row without entering any data in it, then when the `HasChanged` event fires this last new row is included in those to be added to the database. I then get an error because I cannot put that record in the database because of the null values. I would like to exclude this row in that particular situation as it shouldn't be treated as one to be added. Below is my current code:

```
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Grid.Rows
        If Not row.IsNewRow Then
            Dim cellValue As String = String.Empty
            For i = 1 To row.Cells.Count - 1
                cellValue = row.Cells(i).Value.ToString
                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(cellValue) Then
                    MsgBox("All fields has to be filled out")
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next

    marke.MakeChangesDS()

Public Sub MakeChangesDataSet() Implements IDAL.MakeChangesDataSet
    If Not GetGeschaftDataSet.HasChanges Then
        MessageBox.Show("No changes to be done", "Informacja", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
    Else
        Dim i As Integer
        Try
            Using MyConnection = New SqlConnection(strcon)
                Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM T_Marke", MyConnection)
                    MyConnection.Open()
                    ' Create a data adapter in the method and throw it away afterwards
                    Using GetProjectsDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                        Dim cmdbuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(GetProjectsDataAdapter)
                        i = GetProjectsDataAdapter.Update(GetGeschaftDataSet, "trial1")
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
            MessageBox.Show("Updated" & i & " marks", "Informacja", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

I think I should check and exclude it in the MakeChangesDataSet function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SqlDataAdapter class has an event handler called [RowUpdating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.rowupdating(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) that allows you to check if your row is valid or not and cancel the Update of that row if you choose to do so.

```
.....
Using GetProjectsDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
   Dim cmdbuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(GetProjectsDataAdapter)
   AddHandler GetProjectsDataAdapter.RowUpdating, AddressOf onUpdate
   i = GetProjectsDataAdapter.Update(GetGeschaftDataSet, "trial1")
   RemoveHandler GetProjectsDataAdapter.RowUpdating, AddressOf onUpdate
End Using
```

This event is called for each row that needs to be updated before the actual update/insert/delete occurs. The event handler code receives all the info required to decide what to do with the data. You get the `StatementType` that tells you if this is an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE operation. Then you can decide what to do with the row setting the `SqlRowUpdatingEventArgs.Status` before any exception is raised by your database engine.

```
Sub OnUpdate(sender as Object, args As SqlRowUpdatingEventArgs)
     If args.StatementType = StatementType.Insert Then
        if Not IsYourRowValid(args.Row) Then
           args.Status = UpdateStatus.SkipThisRow
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```